# UIKeyBoard resize on orientation change to landscape

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitoolbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uikeyboard

This is very rookie question. I have a UIToolBar at the bottom which is supposed to animatedly move up and down with key board when the UIKeyBoard is displayed. I got that working with the help of UIKeyBoard Notifications. The view we are talking about has split view enabled. When device orientation is landscape, both the views as columns are shown [hope that makes sense].

When key board is shown, i do this

```
CGSize keyBoardSize = [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]CGRectValue].size;

CGRect toolbarFrame= [BottomToolBar frame];
toolbarFrame.origin.y -= keyBoardSize.height;    
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
BottomToolBar .frame = viewFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

when key board is hiiden i do this

```
toolbarFrame.origin.y += keyBoardSize.height;
```

My Problem is when device orientation changes to landscape, when the key board is visible the bottom tool bar is gone. I see it move up quickly. I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone help please? Also, is there a way to NOT make the key board span across both the views in the split view?

Answer (score 10):

I have this problem too, all I can think of is dismissing the keyboard and reshowing it (resign and then become first responder again). But that seems very unsatisfactory.

Note also you should be converting the rect from screen coordinates to the view's coordinates. (The screen coordinates don't rotate.)

```
CGRect keyboardRect = [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]CGRectValue];
keyboardRect = [[BottomToolBar superview] convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];
```

UPDATE: You must register for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, then your action will be called when the interface rotates :)

Also see:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/181482#181482

Comment: This conversion is essential if you are trying to keep a toolbar above the keyboard's frame and the In-Call Status Bar shows up. You can test this in the simulator with the keyboard command CMD + Y

Answer (score 6):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[aNotification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    CGFloat keyboardHeight;
    switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.height;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.width;
            break;
    }

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    CGRect rect = table.frame;
    rect.size.height -= keyboardHeight;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboardShow" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    table.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[aNotification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    CGFloat keyboardHeight;
    switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.height;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.width;
            break;
    }

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    CGRect rectTable = table.frame;
    rectTable.size.height += keyboardHeight;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    table.frame = rectTable;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: dont forget to [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; on viewDidUnload and dealloc

Comment: FYI: You can use handy `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait` macro instead of that big `switch` and `case` monster. :)

Answer (score 4):

UITextFields have an inputAccessoryView property that permits adding a UIToolBar above the UIKeyboard.

Comment: Yes, but OP wants the toolbar to be visible at the bottom of the screen when the keyboard is hidden.

Comment: No problem, just set the toolbar at the bottom as the inputAccessoryView and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { // Or somewhere else
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(kbDidChange:) UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)kbDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrame = [[messageBar superview] convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];

    CGRect ol = messageBar.frame; // messageBar is your UIToolbar..
    ol.origin.y = keyboardFrame.origin.y-44;
    messageBar.frame = ol;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could consider explaining this code, and why it answers the question at hand?

Answer (score 0):

These answers work well, except for external keyboards.  When a hardware keyboard is present, it looks like the "height" property of the keyboard frame passed in the message is still the same as it would be with a virtual keyboard, meaning this code subtracts the height from the view frame for a non-existent keyboard (creating an awkward space).

The best solution I've found is to notice that the "y" property of the keyboard frame is specified to be at the bottom of the screen (implying that the virtual keyboard is actually present, just off the screen).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set option `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` for block based animation, or

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
BottomToolBar.frame = viewFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

in your case. Then the view will not get a sudden movement when changing orientation from portrait to landscape.